# Does strict group completion preserve weak equivalences?

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

Let $i : \mathbf{Grp}\to \mathbf{Mon}$ denote the forgetful functor from groups to monoids. It has a left adjoint, $(-)^{gp}$, which one could call group completion.

We have an induced functor $\mathbf{sMon}\to \mathbf{sGrp}$ between simplicial monoids and simplicial groups, which is again left adjoint to the inclusion. I'll use the same notation for the two functors.

> Does $(-)^{gp} : \mathbf{sMon\to sGrp}$ preserve weak equivalences ?

**Motivation :** with the usual model structures on both sides, the forgetful functor $\mathbf{sGrp\to sMon}$ is clearly right Quillen, and preserves weak equivalences, so its right-derived functor can be "computed as itself".

On the other hand, I'd like to know if the same can be said of the left-derived functor of $(-)^{gp}$. The homotopical version of the group completion of a topological monoid $M$ is usually defined as $\Omega BM$; and it is (at the derived level) a left adjoint to the inclusion of grouplike $E_1$-spaces into $E_1$-spaces - I'm interested in knowing how far apart those constructions are.

I think I can already prove a partial result which encompasses the abelian case and also the connected case : if $f : M\to N$ is a weak equivalence and $H_*(M), H_*(N)$ satisfy the Ore condition with respect to the image of $\pi_0(M)$ (resp. $\pi_0(N)$) under $\pi_*(|M|)\to H_*(M)$  then $f^{gp} : M^{gp}\to N^{gp}$ is a weak equivalence (this is because $|M^{gp}|, |N^{gp}|$ are simple spaces, so it suffices to prove that $f^{gp}$ is a homology equivalence, and the Ore condition allows one to give an easy description of $H_*(M^{gp})$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does (−)^gp: sMon→sGrp preserve weak equivalences ?

No, not at all.

For a counterexample, take the nerve
of the skeleton of the symmetric monoidal category of finite sets and their bijections.

This is a simplicial monoid, whose homotopy group completion
is weakly equivalent to the sphere spectrum
by the Barratt–Priddy–Quillen theorem.
The sphere spectrum has nontrivial higher homotopy groups,
whereas the (strict) group completion does not.

For a positive answer, one may observe that
weak equivalences between retracts of free simplicial monoids are preserved.

Comment: You probably mean to take for $M$ a commutative monoid, for $BM$ to be a simplicial monoid, right ? And do you have an explicit example in mind where the derived group completion has higher homotopy groups ?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi: Yes; I added an explicit example.

Comment: Is there a quick argument for why the strict group completion has no higher homotopy groups ?

Comment: (it seems to me that here $N(Fin)$ is not of the form $BM$ for any $M$ so the previously written argument does not apply)

Comment: @MaximeRamzi: The many-objects version of same argument applies: the skeleton is a strict monoidal category, so the group completion of its nerve is the nerve of its group completion.

Comment: Ok, but how do you know that the group completion of this monoidal category has no higher homotopy groups ?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi: It's a monoidal groupoid, and nerves of groupoids have no higher homotopy groups.

Comment: Yes, I realized in the meantime that it had to be a groupoid (by a core-type argument), thanks a lot, that's a great example !